# JavaScript submit(); problem in IE / Safari / FF for Mac

Tags: php, javascript, forms, submit

I'm writing a Facebook application and I want to submit a form using JavaScript. This works perfectly on Windows: Opera, Chrome, FF. But not on IE and Mac: FF, Safari.

This is the situation:

Function:

```
function postScore(){ 
document.getElementById('idscore').value = document.getElementById('countScore').innerHTML;
document.getElementById('idtime').value = document.getElementById('countTime').innerHTML;
document.forms["myScore"].submit();
}
```

Form:

```
<form action="score.php" id="myScore" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="score" id="idscore" />
<input type="text" name="time" id="idtime" />
</form>
```

Trigger for function:

```
<a href="#" onclick="postScore();">Submit</a>
```

Score.php does not receive any information (checked with print_r($_POST)) in the previously named browsers. As you can see, I made sure that the Id's and Names are different as some browsers mix these up. Any help would be highly appreciated, I'm working on this for 2 days already..

Comment: What do the `#countScore` and `#countTime` elements look like? Have you checked that *they're* being used properly in the problematic browsers? The form won't submit if one of the previous two lines in `postScore()` fails. Have you tried using e.g. IE8's JavaScript debugger?

Comment: Yep I did check that actually; countScore and countTime are put correctly in the idscore & idtime fields.. any other ideas?

Comment: (JavaScript debugger has no complaints)

Answer (score 1):

use jQuery like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myscore").submit(function() {
    $("#container").innerHTML = $(this).find("#idscore").val;
    $("#container2").innerHTML = $(this).find("#idtime").val;
    return false; // so it does not actually execute the submit
  });
});
```

Comment: Thx Geeo, how and where should I use this?

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="score.php" name="myScore" id="myScore" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="score" id="idscore" />
<input type="text" name="time" id="idtime" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately this doesn't help. Other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try giving your form an id and then use `document.getElementById('yourformid').submit();`

Answer (score 0):

IE's `getElementById` is not case sensitive (at least in every version i checked). You should rename your form to `scoreSubmitForm` or something.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any element with an id or name of "submit" anywhere on the page ? If so, try changing that to something different as it could be causing a conflict.

Also, you can try adding a `name="myScore"` attribute to the form tag too.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use the id of the form just make document.getElementById("myScore").submit, or you can add a name="myScore" in the form attributs.